# Why is my dynamically created checkbox value being parsed as null

Tags: javascript

I need to create a checkbox input dynamically in javaScript and parse a hardcoded value (test in the below examples). When alerting out the result, val is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<input onchange='doNotShowClicked(" + 'test' + ");' style='vertical-align:middle;' type='checkbox' />
function doNotShowClicked(val){ alert(val); }
```

Comment: Could you please show us how you are adding checkbox?

Comment: Is this vanilla JS? You cannot call a function like you are doing.

Comment: It is vanilla JS yes and I can call the function like I am doing as doNotShowClicked is called, just not with the value

Comment: ``test`` is throwing error **Unterminated string literal.**

Comment: Is this input being built inside a JS function? If not, where are you expecting a `test` string to come from? (Assuming it's meant to be dynamic from the string building) Also, your `+` seem to be inside the string, rather than concatenating strings? Long story short: I think we need a more complete example of the problem.

Comment: The input is being built in javaScript and the string test is hard coded not a dynamic value